# How to set hitespace management for dockerized lucee server?

Tags: docker, lucee, mura

I have dockerized site build upon Mura CMS and I need to change Whitespace management of Lucee to not default value.

Docker file: blueriver/docker-muracms:7.1-commandbox-lucee5

So wondering if does exist environment variable to cover that purpose.

Comment: Make sure you check this post on the Lucee forums:
https://dev.lucee.org/t/lucee-configuration-options/321

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about it.